# Compare sets inside a set

Tags: java, lambda, set, guava, lambdaj

I have a set like this :

```
Set<Set<Node>> NestedSet = new HashSet<Set<Node>>();

[[Node[0], Node[1], Node[2]], [Node[0], Node[2], Node[6]], [Node[3], Node[4], Node[5]]]
```

I want to compare and merge sets that are inside the nested set. 
[0,1,2] and [0,2,6] has element in common.  so should merge them to form 0,1,2,6.

The output should be like this:

```
[[Node[0], Node[1], Node[2], Node[6]], [Node[3], Node[4], Node[5]]]
```

Is there any efficient way?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/google/guava to have intersection between two nested set if intersection > 0 then you merge the two sets. Of course this is not the most efficient way because you have to compare in the worst case O(n^2) elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Collections.disjoint(Collection c1, Collection c2)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) to check  two specified collections have no elements in common.

Btw make sure your `Node` class implemented `hashCode` and `equals`

```
Set<Set<Node>> result = new HashSet<Set<Node>>();
for (Set<Node> s1 : NestedSet) {
    Optional<Set<Node>> findFirst = result.stream().filter(p -> !Collections.disjoint(s1, p)).findFirst();
    if (findFirst.isPresent()){
        findFirst.get().addAll(s1); 
    }
    else {
        result.add(s1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much  for your help. It worked!  But if I want to add it to  S1  set, only  when  it has  two  common elements, then how  it  should be ?  something like this : if (findFirst.isPresent() and count =2) then add?? Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes you can do it with using retainAll function :
Optional<Set<Node>> findFirst = result.stream().filter(p -> {
 HashSet<Node> temp = new HashSet<>(s1);
 temp.retainAll(p);
 return temp.size() == 2;
}).findFirst();

Comment: Thanks a lot again !  but something went wrong with this. This is the follow up . [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974460/merge-sets-when-two-elements-in-common) .  Could you refer this link.